# Regular expression curvy brackets in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
a = '{CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}}{CGSize=dd}dd{CSize=aa}'
```

Currently I am using this `re` statement to get desired result:

```
filter(None, re.split("\\{(.*?)\\}", a))
```

But this gives me:

```
['CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd', '}}', 'CGSize=dd', 'dd', 'CSize=aa']
```

which is incorrect for my current situation, I need a list like this:

```
['CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}', 'CGSize=dd', 'dd', 'CSize=aa']
```

Comment: You can't do this with python's regex flavor. Arbitrarily nested structures are beyond it's capabilities. Walk the string character-by-character, and maintain a `depth` count which you increase when encountering `{` and decrease when incountering `}`. When you get back to `0` take the substring from where you found the first `{` to there.

Comment: @m.buettner is correct.  You need to write a parser to parser on the tokens, this case open and close braces, to produce your result.  It should be easy to do, given the simplicity of the problem.

Comment: I thought that python can do it for me :D, but yes, it won't be any problem to write parser like that, tnx :)

Comment: What's the idea exactly, I don't completely see the logic in the result you want to get. You do have recusrive backreferences for regexes though so maybe it is possible, but I just don't completely understand what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an alternative regex module for Python I really like that supports recursive patterns:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

```
pip install regex
```

Then you can use a recursive pattern in your regex as demonstrated in this script:

```
import regex
from pprint import pprint


thestr = '{CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}}{CGSize=dd}dd{CSize=aa}'

theregex = r'''
    (
        {
            (?<match>
                [^{}]*
                (?:
                    (?1)
                    [^{}]*
                )+
                |
                [^{}]+
            )
        }
        |
        (?<match>
            [^{}]+
        )
    )
'''

matches = regex.findall(theregex, thestr, regex.X)

print 'all matches:\n'
pprint(matches)

print '\ndesired matches:\n'
print [match[1] for match in matches]
```

This outputs:

```
all matches:

[('{CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}}', 'CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}'),
 ('{CGSize=dd}', 'CGSize=dd'),
 ('dd', 'dd'),
 ('{CSize=aa}', 'CSize=aa')]

desired matches:

['CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}', 'CGSize=dd', 'dd', 'CSize=aa']
```

Comment: Is there a way to get `theregex` to match the inner braced strings,   `{CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}` and `{CGPoint=dd}`?

Comment: @unutbu It's probably possible somehow, but from the matches you get back from a regex you won't know the depth of the nested brackets. If you want to know the depth, the solution you provided will be better.

Answer (score 4):

As @m.buettner points out in the comments, Python's implementation of regular expressions can't match pairs of symbols nested to an arbitrary degree.  (Other languages can, notably current versions of Perl.)  The Pythonic thing to do when you have text that regexs can't parse is to use a recursive-descent parser.

There's no need to reinvent the wheel by writing your own, however; there are a number of easy-to-use parsing libraries out there.  I recommend [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which lets you define a grammar directly in your code and easily attach actions to matched tokens.  Your code would look something like this:

```
import pyparsing

lbrace = Literal('{')
rbrace = Literal('}')  
contents = Word(printables)
expr = Forward()
expr << Combine(Suppress(lbrace) + contents + Suppress(rbrace) + expr)

for line in lines:
    results = expr.parseString(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) has a `nestedExpr` function for matching nested expressions:

```
import pyparsing as pp

ident = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
expr = pp.nestedExpr("{", "}") | ident

thestr = '{CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}}{CGSize=dd}dd{CSize=aa}'
for result in expr.searchString(thestr):
    print(result)
```

yields

```
[['CGPoint=', ['CGPoint=d', ['CGPoint=dd']]]]
[['CGSize=dd']]
['dd']
[['CSize=aa']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code.  It creates a stack of strings and pops them when a close brace is encountered.  Some extra logic to handle the fact that the first braces encountered are not included in the array.

```
String source = "{CGPoint={CGPoint=d{CGPoint=dd}}}{CGSize=dd}dd{CSize=aa}";
Array results;
Stack stack;

foreach (match in source.match("[{}]|[^{}]+")) {
    switch (match) {
        case '{':
           if (stack.size == 0) stack.push(new String()); // add new empty string
           else stack.push('{'); // child, so include matched brace.
        case '}':
           if (stack.size == 1) results.add(stack.pop()) // clear stack add to array
           else stack.last += stack.pop() + '}"; // pop from stack and concatenate to previous
        default:
           if (stack.size == 0) results.add(match); // loose text, add to results
           else stack.last += match;  // append to latest member.
    }
}
```